# vue.js form validation and ajax submit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, validation, vue.js

I'm trying to use [vue.js](http://vuejs.org/) to do form validation and when the element is valid to submit it via ajax.  But I can't get past the validation part.

My html:

```
<div id='form' 'v-on'="change:updateForm">
<form>
    <select id="selects" name="selected_id" v-model='form.selected_id | selectValidator'>
        <option value="">Please choose one
            <option value='1'>Select 1</option>
            <option value='2'>Select 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<div v-show="!validation.selected_id">Select cannot be blank</div>
<div v-show="validation.selected_id">{{form.selected_id}}</div>
<div v-show="validation.selected_id">{{validation.selected_id}}</div>
```

My javascript:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#form',
filters: {
    selectValidator: function (val) {
        this.validation.selected_id = !! val
        return val
    }
},
data: {
    form: {
        selected_id: ''
    },
    validation: {
        selected_id: false
    }
},
methods: {
    updateForm: function (e) {
        console.log(this.validation.selected_id)
        if (this.validation.selected_id) {
            console.log("make ajax call")
        }
    }
}
```

})

When looking into the console I see `this.validation.selected_id` as false instead of what it really is when it's printed out: `true`

Here's a [jsfiddle for testing](http://jsfiddle.net/nictrix/Nr8Lp), but it doesn't show the console log.

Comment: There is now a [vue-validator](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-validator) plugin available for Vue. It works a lot like the one for AngularJS.

Comment: Thank you for sending me the link

Comment: Have you seen the [vue-contextable](https://github.com/xpepermint/vue-contextable)? [Contextable.js](https://github.com/xpepermint/contextablejs) is build for server-side and client-side validation.

Comment: Thanks @xpepermint - I'll have to look into it, but as of now I'm no longer working on Vue.js - things have probably gotten much better now.

Answer (score 0):

The first line has single quotes around 'v-on' when there shouldn't be any:

```
<div id='form' v-on="change:updateForm">
```

Here's a [JSFiddle with the working version](http://jsfiddle.net/Nr8Lp/2/)

Comment: If you create a local html file with these items and run it, you'll see the console will log false when you select either one, then select the 2nd one and it will log true and also log this output: "make ajax call" - unfortunately your answer does not fix the problem.